# What is $\dim(V^V)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Where $V$ is a vector space and $V^V=\left\{ f\mid f\colon V\rightarrow V \right\}$.

I proved that $V^V$ is a vector space so $\dim\left(V^V\right)$ is well defined.

Comment: Is $V$ finite dimensional or infinite?

Comment: $V$ is finite dimensional.

Comment: Have you tried playing with simple examples? E.g. that $V = \mathbb{R}$, what happens?

Comment: Are your functions any old function, or must they be linear?

Comment: Which $f$ are you considering?  All set-theoretic functions $V\to V$ or just linear maps $V\to V$?

Comment: Did you by any chance mean not the set of all functions from V to V, but the set of all linear functions from V to V?

Answer (score 6):

If $\dim V=0$, then one readily finds that $V^V$ is a singleton set, hence $\dim(V^V)=0$, too.

If $V$ is a vector space over a finite field $\Bbb F_q$ and of finite dimension $n$, then $V$ is a set of $q^n$ elements. Then one quickly finds that $V^V\cong V^{q^n}$ is of dimension $n^{q^n}$.

If $V$ is an infinite set (that is, either of infnite dimension over an arbitrary field, or of any positive dimension over in infinite field), then certainly $\dim(V^V)$ is infinite. If needed, you could still make more precise statements about the exact - infinite - cardinality, but I suppose yo do not want to go down that rabbit hole ...

Answer (score 1):

As a continuation of Hagen von Eitzen's answer, the notation $V^V$ is usually used to express the product $\prod_{v\in V}V$, which comprises a function space over $V$.

This is equivalent (or isomorphic depending on the details) to the set of sequences (or nets, or whatever) indexed by $V$ whose elements belong to $V$.

If, $V$ is infinite, then you have the choice of expressing its dimension as either a cardinal or ordinal number.

If you want a cardinal, then consider that $V^V$ is the special case of $W^V=\prod_{v\in V}W$ for which $W=V$. WLOG, suppose $W=\mathbb{R}$ and $V=\mathbb{N}$ (yes, I know $\mathbb{N}$, isn't a field but stick with me here). Then, $W^V=\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ - the set of sequences of real numbers indexed by naturals. For each such sequence $\mathbf{a}\in\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$, we may write...

$$\mathbf{a}=\bigoplus_{n\in\mathbb{N}}a_n=\langle a_1,a_2,\cdots\rangle$$

Thus, the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ is then the length of the sequence $\mathbf{a}$, which is just the cardinality of the natural numbers. The same holds if we select any other sets for $W^V$; $\dim_{card}(W^V)=|V|$

Now, if you want an *ordinal*, you first need to define an order on $V$. Let $\mathfrak{V}=(V,\leq_V)$ where $\leq_V$ is the ordering relation on $V$. For each $\mathbf{w}\in V^V$, let $\mathfrak{U}_w=(U_w,\leq_w)$, where $U_w=\{\mathbf{u}\in V^2\mid w_{u_1}=u_2\}$ and $\forall\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\in U_w.\mathbf{x}\leq_w\mathbf{y}\iff x_1\leq_V y_1$ (this is basically treating each element of $V^V$ like a Hausdorff tuple).

Trivially, for each $\mathbf{w}\in V^V$, $\mathfrak{U}_w$ is homomorphic to $\mathfrak{V}$. If the ordering of $\mathfrak{V}$ is such that for all $\mathbf{w}\in V^V$ there is a bijection $V\to U_w$, then $\forall\mathbf{w}\in V^V.\mathfrak{V}\cong\mathfrak{U}_w$. If the order type of $\mathfrak{U}_w$ is the same for all $\mathbf{w}\in V^V$, then the dimension of $V$, expressed as an ordinal, will be the order type of $\mathfrak{V}$.

Answer (score 0):

$V^V = \operatorname{End}{V}$ has dimension $(\dim{V})^2$ (assuming $V$ is finite-dimensional). To see this, try to find a basis of $\operatorname{End}{V}$.

Edit: I assumed you meant linear maps; if not, disregard my answer.

Comment: I'm not sure that OP meant to consider only linear maps.

Answer (score -2):

If V has finite dimension n then $V^V$ has dimension $n^n$.  If V has countable dimension then $V^V$ has countable dimension.  If V has uncountable dimension then $V^V$ has uncountable dimension.

Comment: yes, but why is it $n^n$?

Comment: It does not have dimension $n^n$.

Comment: This is not so.

Answer (score -2):

Let us define a function: $$\eta (x,y)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
0\: \: x\neq y\\ 
1\: \: x=y
\end{matrix}\right. $$ for all $y\in V$.
 We claim then that $\beta =\left \{ \eta (x,y)\, |\, y\in V \right \}$ is a basis.

Let us look at the sum: $\sum_{y\in V}\alpha _{y}\eta (x,y)=0$ for all $x$. we can say then :$$\sum_{y\in V}\alpha _{y}\eta (x,y)=\alpha _{x}\eta (x,x)=0$$
this applies that $\alpha _{x}=0$ for all $x$. thus we conclude that $\beta$ is linearly independent.
We can also say that for all $f\in V^V$: $$f(x)=\sum_{y\in V}f(y)\eta (x,y)$$ Thus we conclude that $\beta$ spans $V^V$.

Thus we can say $\beta$ is a basis and $\dim(V^V)=\left | V \right |$.

Comment: What if $V$ is infinite?  What does your sum mean then?

Comment: Also, this is incorrect:  see Hagen's correct answer and how it disagrees with yours.

Comment: Yes , I proved it only for finite V.

Comment: Also, at least three people are asking for clarification to your problem:  all maps or only linear maps?  This affects the answer.  You should help them help you by clarifying.

Comment: Maps in general.

Comment: Even in the finite case, $f(x)=\sum_{y\in V}f(y)\eta(x,y)$ does not prove what you want; it is not a linear combination of the $\eta(x,y)$ as the coefficients $f(y)$ are not scalars, but vectors in $V$.

Comment: Furthermore, the $\eta(x,y)$ don't even lie in $V^V$ unless you can sensibly explain what the vector $1\in V$ is supposed to be.

Comment: I’m sorry! V is a field F.

Comment: Well then you're only proving it in the $1$-dim case.

Comment: If you are considering the $F$-vector space $F^F$, then at least your proof of linear independence of this set is fine. It is, however, only a spanning set when $F$ is finite. Otherwise your infinite sums are not well-defined. Specifically, for $F=\mathbb{R}$, you can't write the constant $1$ function as linear combination of the $\eta(-,y)$.